# Graded field over integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, graded-rings

In a $\mathbb Z$-graded field $R$, prove that $R=R_0$. Use the fact that all units in a graded domain are homogenous or otherwise.

Try: Let $x_n$ be any nonzero element. Then it is homogeneous and unit. Then there is $y_m$ such that $ x_ny_m=1 $. As $ 1 \in R_0$, $m=-n$. From here how can I show $ n=0$ ?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: See Remark 1.3.10 in C. Nastasescu, F. Van Oystaeyen, Methods of Graded Rings, Springer 2004. However there appears to be a typo (at least in my version), it says $ab_{n_1}$ is the unique term of smallest degree, but in fact just $b_{n_1}$ is the unique term of smallest degree.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow ,   plz give me the link of Methods of graded rings.

Comment: why would a non-zero element necessarily be homogeneous?

Comment: Non zero elements are units in a field and in a graded daomain, units are homogenous.

Comment: I would say the problem is not very well worded: there is a notion of graded field, in which all *homogeneous* non-zero elements are invertible. I think it would be clearer to say "In a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded ring which is a field".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that $x_n+y_{-n}$ is non-zero element and hence is a unit in $R$. So $x_n+y_{-n} $ is homogenous, which is possible only when n=0.